# Implement interface and change parameter to specific object-type

Tags: kotlin, interface

I want to implement an interface and change the parameter in the `create(any : Any)` function to `create(benefitModel : BenefitModel)`in the `BenefitStore`-class which implements the interface. 
This does not work and I get the following error message: 
"`Class 'BenefitStore' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun create(O: Any)...`".

What is the best way for me to solve this problem?

**StoreInterface.kt**

```
interface StoreInterface {
    fun findAll(): List<Any>
    fun create(any : Any)
    fun update(any: Any)
    fun delete(any: Any)
}
```

**BenefitStore.kt**

```
class BenefitStore: StoreInterface, AnkoLogger {

override fun create(benefitModel: BenefitModel) {
...
}
```

Comment: To clarify why it's not possible with the interface as defined above: Implementing an interface says “This class can do all _these_ things.”  In this case, it means you can call `create("ABC")` or `create(1)` or with any other (non-null) parameter.  But the class above doesn't allow that — so it's not fully implementing the interface.  You either need to expand what the class can do, or (as Todd demonstrates) reduce what the interface demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `StoreInterface` to be generic.

I've also take the liberty of removing the redundant `...Interface` on it, which is not idiomatic.

```
interface Store<T> {
    fun findAll(): List<T>
    fun create(arg : T)
    fun update(arg: T)
    fun delete(arg: T)
}
```

By using generics, you are telling Kotlin that `T` is a placeholder type that will be specified by the class implementing the interface:

```
class BenefitStore: Store<BenefitModel>, AnkoLogger {

    override fun create(arg: BenefitModel) {
        //...
    }
}
```

So in this case, `Store` will work with `BenefitModel`s only. And all of the functions overridden in `BenefitStore` that came from `Store`, will require `BenefitModel` instances.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question!